# How can I hide and show multiple divs and change button content at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide divs and change the text content of buttons at the same time.

**Problem:** The issue I'm having is that the div is hidden but the content of the button does not change.

I'll be using multiple buttons to hide and show multiple images and texts.

HTML

```
 <div class="hide-show-divs">
   <p>Some content in a div</p>
   <p>More content in a div</p>
 </div>

 <div class="hide-show-divs">
   <p>Some content in a div</p>
   <p>More content in a div</p>
 </div>
```

Button

```
<div>
  <button class="hide-show-divs-btn" onclick="toggle()">Hide Divs</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggle() {
  var hideShowDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("hide-show-divs");
  for(var i = 0; i < hideShowDivs.length; i++){
    if (hideShowDivs[i].style.display === "none") {
      hideShowDivs[i].style.display = "block";
      changeBtnText();
    } else {
      hideShowDivs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function changeBtnText() {
  var hideShowImgBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("hide-show-divs-btn");
  for(var i = 0; i < hideShowImgBtn.length; i++)
    if(hideShowImgBtn[i].value =="Show divs") {
      hideShowImgBtn[i].value = "Hide divs";
    }else {
      hideShowImgBtn[i].value = "Show divs";
    }
  }
```

What should happen is:

1. The first time I click on the button - I want the divs to be hidden as well as the text in that button to change to 'Show Divs'.
2. The second time I click on the button - I want the divs to be shown as well as the text in that button to be changed back to 'Hide Divs'.

Comment: what is not working? what behaviour are u currently getting?

Comment: @FutureCake The problem I'm having is that the content of the button does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have pretty much most of functionality just few issues

1. div wrapping button has quote in it, synatx error
2. inside of toggle function you need to invoke changeBtnText in order to change
3. button doesn't have value, so your if fails, you can use innerText for it

```js
function toggle() {
  var hideShowDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("hide-show-divs");
  changeBtnText(); // Invoking changeBtnText added
  for(var i = 0; i < hideShowDivs.length; i++){
    if (hideShowDivs[i].style.display === "none") {
      hideShowDivs[i].style.display = "block";
      changeBtnText();
    } else {
      hideShowDivs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function changeBtnText() {
  var hideShowImgBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("hide-show-divs-btn");
  for(var i = 0; i < hideShowImgBtn.length; i++)
    // Using innerText instead of value
    if(hideShowImgBtn[i].innerHTML =="Show divs") {
      hideShowImgBtn[i].innerHTML = "Hide divs";
    }else {
      hideShowImgBtn[i].innerHTML = "Show divs";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I applied your changes but the text content of the button still does not change

Comment: Thanks.  It works when I change **innerText** to **innerHTML** . Not sure why innerText does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery witch is much easier:

First step: Add jQuery

```
 <head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Now the code:

```
   $(".hide-show-divs-btn").click(function() {

      $( ".hide-show-divs" ).toggle();




      $(this).text() === 'Hide Divs'
      ? $(this).text('Show Divs')
      : $(this).text('Hide Divs')

     })
```